# blogdown:::new_post_addin() causes unsolved error

Tags: r, blogdown

I'm trying to create new post with `new_post_addin()`.

then I got:

```
> Listening on [http://127.0.0.1:6651](http://127.0.0.1:6651/)
Warning in file(con, "r") :
cannot open file 'Content "C:\\Users\\82103\\Desktop\\ssangblog\\content\\post\\2021-12-14-1234\\index.md"/index.md': Invalid argument
Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
> 9: shiny::runApp
> 8: shiny::runGadget
> 7: eval
> 6: eval
> 5: sys.source
> 2: source_addin
> 1: blogdown:::new_post_addin
>
```

**First, there's something strange in file directory** :

```
'Content "C:\\Users\\82103\\Desktop\\ssangblog\\content\\post\\2021-12-14-234\\index.md"/index.md'
```

I have no idea why there's 'double backslash' and two 'index.md' with 'Content "~" '.
I just think there must have been an error in the code handling the file directory.

**Second, The only file created in the content folder is index.md** where the tags I entered are not properly entered.
I also created R markdown, why is it '.md'...
[index.md](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySum1.png)

It may be a problem that derives from the first.

To solve my problem, I refered the following url.

https://www.py4u.net/discuss/896387

https://d.cosx.org/d/422702-blogdownnew-post-addin

I couldn't find a fundamental solution, and the only answer was to fix it through an update.

I referred to the following url to check where the error occurred with traceback.

- news debugging blogdown
  https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/main/NEWS.md
- to look at the new_post_addin, source_addin
  https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/a555322e2ca1ec66ac37dd706720180284760210/R/addin.R
- new_post.R
  https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blame/main/inst/scripts/new_post.R

As a result of reviewing them, I realized that it was beyond my ability.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/667) and has been fixed in the dev version of **blogdown** (as indicated in [NEWS.md](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/main/NEWS.md)). Please install the dev version:

```
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```